# Package com.cedarsoftware does not exist! Java

Tags: java, import, package

I just had to implement JsonWriter today and when Im trying to get it working the import I need to do does not work. Im baffled, I really dont know how to fix it.

The way Im importing it right now is `import com.cedarsoftware.*;` and it tells me that it doesnt exist. I had already added the classpath and also added the .jar to the lib directory in my folder.

Any ideas of why it isnt working?

Comment: What is the "it" that's telling you it doesn't exist? Are you using an IDE?

Comment: @snickers10m Im using JCreator, so when I compile I get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I supossed that you are using [Json-io library from Github](https://github.com/jdereg/json-io/tree/master/src).

- If you are using Maven, put this code into your proyect config

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.cedarsoftware</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-io</artifactId>
      <version>4.1.8</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- If not, create al directories of **com/cedarsoftware/util/io** and put all source file code there. And then use:

  ```
  import com.cedarsoftware.util.io.JsonWriter;
  ```